# CSS Grid or HTML Table

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-grid

I have something that could definitely be an HTML Table, however, I wonder if creating it as a CSS Grid would be better.

[image: Section as an HTML Table or CSS Grid]

The 1, 2, 3, 4 row may or may not be there depending on the data that is pulled in. However, those headers (1,2,3,4) will be replaced with different names, again depending on the data. And I want the data below them in each row to be in alignment and the same width as those columns.

I know how to fairly easily make this work with HTML Tables, with the main nuance being the Col-2 header would need to colspan potentially.

I'd assume this is a fairly straightforward task with CSS grid, however, I figured to ask here.

Comment: While I'm sure it's possible to achieve the pictured format with either HTML tables are CSS grid, since you are using dynamic data, it's probably going to be easier to dynamically generate and update HTML than it will be to generate and update the appropriate CSS, in a way that's also responsive to screen sizes. Also, if you are displaying something that's semantically a table, it's usually a best practice to use semantic HTML tables.

Comment: If it's displaying data, it's a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather use HTML table. Because it makes your code look easier to understand with `<th>` for headers and `<td>` for cells data. On the other hand, CSS grid requires you to declare more classes and style it just to make it work like the HTML table, which takes more time, effort.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Grid is more preferable for large data tables when they need to be displayed on tablets and smart phones. Some columns can be hidden on tablets and smartphones, or even layout can be changed from rows to columns

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer working with html tables. HTML , , and  tags are supported across browsers and devices. Moreover, grids do not work on HTML email templates. If the use case is for modern applications and modern browsers, grids work perfectly fine, but considering cases of email templates, the HTML table is the perfect one to go with.